# On page refresh, Canvas element turns completely white rendering a white rectangle (on Chrome)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm currently building a website on React, using Next JS, and needed to build a 3D scene. I am using Three JS through it React wrapper React-Three/Fiber.
Basically if I'm using Google Chrome and I reload the website, app build or development server, I get these white flashes where the canvas elements are located. There are 4 Canvas mounted on site, and how many or which one turns white seems to be random.
This does not replicate on say, Safari.

Edit: Im not using the html canvas tag, but the Canvas component from react three fiber, I just run a quick test and it seems to be that the Canvas component is the problem, not seeing the same flicker with regular canvas.

Even if there are models visible in the canvas, the canvas turns white

[White flashes on reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZnWX.gif)

Given that the website's background is really dark, these flashes are really noticeable and ugly.

Thanks in advance.

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer that worked.

Comment: This is just a hunch, but it might be the background color before the first frame renders. Have you tried setting it on CSS? `canvas {background-color: #000}`

Comment: @Marquizzo I did try that, but its not related, since per my understanding the Canvas element renders with a translucent background. When setting the bg color manually it would get resetted too.

I've just fixed it, I was logging in to resolve the question. The issue was actually 2 css properties that were set on different parent components: opacity and filter, my guess is that the Canvas component doesnt play very well with attributes like these, very hard to debug too. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually 2 css properties that were set on different parent components: opacity and filter (for grayscale). My guess is that the Canvas component doesnt play very well with attributes like these that modify all the content's appearance, very hard to debug.